# Gulp Local and CLI version mismatch globally and within project folder

Tags: npm, gulp

I am trying to run Gulp 3.9.0 in my project folder and have downgraded my Gulp via `npm install gulp@3.9.0`. However, it seem like only my local version of gulp is 3.9.0. How do I get my CLI to the same version?

[image: commandLine]

Comment: The CLI is different software, your version numbers will be different.

Comment: @Mark, how do I update my CLI version to 3.9.0?

Comment: You can't, CLI version 2.0.1 is the most current.  It is a different program than gulp3.9 and so has different version numbers.